# How is @ContextConfiguration different from @ComponentScan?

Tags: spring

[@ContextConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html):

> @ContextConfiguration defines class-level metadata that is used to determine how to load and configure an ApplicationContext for integration tests.

[@ComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html):

> Configures component scanning directives for use with @Configuration classes.

Assume the existence of package `com.example.foo.config`. It contains `FooConfig.java`, which is the only file defining beans in that package.

Is `@ContextConfiguration(classes = FooConfig.class)` equivalent to `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.foo.config")`?

Comment: Short answer, yes.

Comment: `@ContextConfiguration` will configure only `FooConfig.class`  while `@ComponentScan`  will configure all the `@Configuration` classes inside `com.example.foo.config` package. So both are not same.

Comment: @GirijaSankarPanda: the implicit assumption is that `FooConfig.java` is the only file that defines beans inside the package. I'll update the text to reflect that.